# Tableau: Calculate the average value for the last 3 records

Tags: tableau-api

I have a time series data fro the different products. i like to calculate the average for each products based on only last 3 values. can you please help me.

Thanks
Kathir

Answer (score 0):

Use `SIZE() - INDEX() + 1`

Drag it to your row or column and convert as discrete. Use table calc if needed

Now you will have an index for each row. Create another calculated field which will be using fix LOD of the above calculated field and when Index = 1 or 2 or 3, it sums it

You will be able to calculate average by diving the field with the sum of fix LOD created

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the suggestions. But still its not clear to me...

For example, I have 3 products with purchase price with respect to the date. I want aggregate and calculate the average price based on last 3 records wrto date.

Comment: The dataset looks like below

SampleDate SamplePoint Sales
6/4/2019         C 5
3/28/2019 C 6
9/20/2018 C 7
7/31/2018 C 8
6/12/2018 C 9
9/30/2015 B 10
8/26/2015 A 100
3/11/2015 B 20
3/11/2015 B 30
2/26/2015 A 200
9/11/2014 B 40
8/26/2014 A 300
5/14/2014 A 400

i want to calculate the average for each product with respect to the last 3 values

Comment: Do you have an excel?